# Find and Replace using another form

Tags: vb.net, replace, find

I have my `frmMain`which has `RichTextBox1` and I have a button `btnfind&Replace`which  whose click event pops out another minute form `frmFindandReplace` which has two textboxes: `TextBoxSearch` and `TextBoxReplace` with two buttons: `replaceButton` and `findButton`. I cannot seem to get my code for instances of finding a word in textbox and an instance of replacing it. Here is my code:

```
Public Class frmFindandReplace

Dim txtClientArea As RichTextBox

Private Sub TextBoxSearch_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxSearch.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub frmFindandReplace_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub replaceButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles replaceButton.Click

End Sub



Protected Friend Sub findButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles findButton.Click
    Dim a As String
    Dim b As String


    a = TextBoxSearch.Text
    b = InStr(StartPosition, a, txtClientArea)

    If b Then txtClientArea.Focus()
    txtClientArea.SelectionStart = b - 1
    txtClientArea.SelectionLength = Len(a)
    txtClientArea.ScrollToCaret()




End Sub
```

The `findButton` code doesnot even work. Throws an error!

> Error 3:  Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'InStr' can be called with these arguments:
>       'Public Function InStr(Start As Integer, String1 As String, String2 As String, [Compare As Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompareMethod = Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompareMethod.Binary]) As Integer': Value of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' cannot be converted to 'String'.
>       'Public Function InStr(String1 As String, String2 As String, [Compare As Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompareMethod = Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompareMethod.Binary]) As Integer': Value of type 'System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox' cannot be converted to 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompareMethod'. C:\Users\Joseph GodwinKE\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\simpleapp\frmFindandReplace.VB   25  13  Simple app

I know I have not done much but am new and all my efforts of searching a solution over the internet have failed! Thank you I hope someone will help me pls.

Comment: Check the [documentation of Instr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx) function here. Is your txtClientArea a string? Surely not. Apart from this you don't initialize that variable anywhere. It is just a declaration of a variable with Nothing as value. Your code will never work.

Answer (score 0):

A few pointers:

InStr returns an integer.
Check the documentation as it'll show you have the search values the wrong way around.
Turn Option Explicit on to help find your issues.

This should work better.

```
Private Sub findButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles findButton.Click

    Dim searchString As String
    Dim findPos As Integer

    Try
        searchString = TextBoxSearch.Text
        findPos = InStr(txtClientArea.Text, searchString)

        If findPos > 0 Then txtClientArea.Focus()
        txtClientArea.SelectionStart = findPos - 1
        txtClientArea.SelectionLength = searchString.Length
        txtClientArea.ScrollToCaret()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An error occurred: ", ex.Message))
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code work you need to pass the reference to the `RichTextBox` present in the first form to the *findandReplace* form.
Otherwise you will not be able to work with that instance of the RichTextBox.

Usually, this means that when you create and open an instance of the *findandReplace* form you pass the reference to the RichTextBox to work with in the call to the constructor. Something like this

```
Dim fReplace As frmFindandReplace = New frmFindandReplace(Me.txtClientArea)
fReplace.Show()
```

Here the New call reaches the constructor of *frmfindandReplace*. This call is usually hidden by VB.NET but you could add it writing explicit code for it

```
Public Class frmFindandReplace

   Dim txtClientArea As RichTextBox
   Public Sub New (ByVal txt as RichTextBox)
        txtClientArea = txt
   End Sub
```

Now the global variable `txtClientArea` inside the *findandReplace* class is assigned to the existing reference of the RichTextBox present in the first form and you could happily work with it

```
Protected Friend Sub findButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles findButton.Click
    Dim a As String

    a = TextBoxSearch.Text
    Dim position = txtClientArea.Find(a, 0, RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase)        
    .....
End Sub
```

And please make yourself a favor and start using the more complete methods available from the NET Framework library and stop using the old fashioned VBA methods.
For example the RichTextBox has a method that does exactly what you are trying to do in code. `Find`, search the content of the textbox and if it founds a match it highlight the text and return the starting position of the text.
There is no replace builtin method but having the position and the length is really simple to implement your own replacing code.

Comment: so how would the whole code for find look like coz when i add the code you posted + mine nothing happens ?

Answer (score 0):

You Have defined b as a string. Change it to an integer. Also Instr doesn't allow you to set a start position, just a string to search and the string to search for and optionally the type of search - Binary or Text.

Finally rather than type **If b then**, use **If b>0 then** rather than turning off Option Strict. It's always better to write code with Option Strict on as it makes you write better code and in the long run is easier to chase down errors